# How to retrieve Assembly Information in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, attributes, .net-assembly, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to retrieve the values of:

- Authors
- Package
- Version
- Release Notes
- Tags

that are defined in the "properties" of a VS 2022 project (and are also in the .csproj file).

Using the syntax of:

```
var myVar => Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<Assembly[Attribute]Attribute>().[Attribute]
```

I am able to get the values of most of the Attributes (Company, Copyright, Description, etc.), but not the values of the attributes listed above.

I have looked at the file

> D:\Path\project\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\project.AssemblyInfo.cs

And see that the Attributes that are available using
*"Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<Assembly[Attribute]Attribute>().[Attribute]"*
are defined in this file.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Wm. Eric Brunsen")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright 2018, Wm. Eric Brunsen, All rights reserved")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("Shooting Range Management Software")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("Range Manager")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("RangeMgr")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetPlatformAttribute("Windows7.0")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatformAttribute("Windows7.0")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to get the Attribute values that are defined in the "properties" UI and .csproj but are not available via the
   *Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<Assembly[Attribute]Attribute>().[Attribute]*
   ?
2. Since the header of the project.AssemblyInfo.cs file header says that it is generated via a a tool, if I add the values of the attributes to this file will they remain or will the be lost each time the app is compiled?

Thanks,

Eric